# Consistent updating of validation state in a custom reactive form control?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to create a material `username` reactive form control using the approach [outlined in this tutorial](https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-custom-form-controls/).

The end result should work in a form like this ( the `fs-username-form` is the custom reactive form component ):

```
<mat-card class="UsernameFormTestCard">
  <form class="UsernameForm" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input
        matInput
        placeholder="First name"
        type="text"
        formControlName="firstName"
      />
      <mat-hint *ngIf="!username">Example Monica</mat-hint>
      <mat-error>Please enter your first name</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <fs-username-form formControlName="username"></fs-username-form>

    <button mat-button type="submit" [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

If the form is valid then the `Submit` button enables.

And it works ... sort of ... It enables reactively ... but not consistently.  The minimum number of characters is set to `4`.  And the submit button enables when the length is `4`.  However if we start removing characters from the `username` the `submit` button only disables after the length of the `username` is `2`.

[This is the Stackblitz demo showing this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vb7eja?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html).

The `username-form.component.ts` is implemented like this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  AbstractControl,
  ControlValueAccessor,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  NG_VALIDATORS,
  NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
  ValidationErrors,
  Validator,
  Validators,
} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'fs-username-form',
  templateUrl: './username-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./username-form.component.css'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: UsernameFormComponent,
    },
    {
      provide: NG_VALIDATORS,
      multi: true,
      useExisting: UsernameFormComponent,
    },
  ],
})
export class UsernameFormComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {
  //=============================================
  // ControlValueAccessor API Methods
  //=============================================
  disabled: boolean = false;
  // Dummy initialization.
  //The implementation is passed in
  // with registerOnChange.
  onChange = (username: string) => {};
  onTouched = () => {};
  touched = false;
  usernameValue = '';

  writeValue(username: any): void {
    this.usernameValue = username;
  }

  //=============================================
  // Registration API Methods
  //=============================================

  registerOnChange(onChange: any): void {
    this.onChange = onChange;
  }

  registerOnTouched(onTouched: any): void {
    this.onTouched = onTouched;
  }

  markAsTouched() {
    if (!this.touched) {
      this.onTouched();
      this.touched = true;
    }
  }

  setDisabledState(disabled: boolean) {
    this.disabled = disabled;
    if (disabled) {
      this.usernameControl?.disable();
    } else {
      this.usernameControl?.enable();
    }
  }

  //=============================================
  // Validator API Methods
  //=============================================
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {
    console.log('VALIDATE IS GETTING CALLED');
    console.log('Is the form valid: ', this.usernameForm.valid);

    if (this.usernameForm.valid) {
      return null;
    }

    let errors: any = {};

    errors = this.addControlErrors(errors, 'username');

    return errors;
  }

  addControlErrors(allErrors: any, controlName: string) {
    const errors = { ...allErrors };
    const controlErrors = this.usernameForm.controls[controlName].errors;

    if (controlErrors) {
      errors[controlName] = controlErrors;
    }
    return errors;
  }

 
  /**
   * Registers a call to onChange to inform
   * parent forms of valueChanges events.
   */
  constructor() {
    this.usernameControl?.valueChanges.subscribe((u) => {
      this.onChange(u);
    });
  }

  public usernameForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    username: new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.minLength(4),
    ]),
  });

  get username() {
    return this.usernameForm.get('username')?.value;
  }

  get usernameControl() {
    return this.usernameForm.get('username');
  }
}
```

The `username-form.component.html` template looks like this:

```
<form class="UsernameForm" [formGroup]="usernameForm">
  <mat-form-field>
    <input
      matInput
      placeholder="username"
      type="text"
      formControlName="username"
    />
    <mat-hint *ngIf="!username">Example Monica</mat-hint>
    <mat-error>Please enter your username</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

As can be seen it implements the `ControlValueAccessor` and  `Validator` interfaces.

Call on `onChange` are made when the user types in the `username` field and, if I understand correctly, this in turn should cause the parent form to call validate on the `username` control.

Why does the `submit` button in the demo form not update consistently or why the `username-form` component does not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working.  Instead of checking whether the form containing the control is valid in the `validate` method, I switched it to check whether the control itself is valid like this:

```
  //=============================================
  // Validator API Methods
  //=============================================
  validate(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null {

    if (this.usernameControl.valid) {
      return null;
    }

    let errors: any = {};

    errors = this.addControlErrors(errors, 'username');

    return errors;
  }
```

And now it works.  [This is a new working demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-49hx6j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fpassword-form%2Fusername-form.component.ts)